# Struggling to convert 1min closing prices data to 5min in R

Tags: r, xts, trading

Asked this question question recently and was advised to use the '**to.minutes5()**' function. However, upon doing so I get the following error:

```
Error in to.period(x, "minutes", k = 5, name = name, ...) : 
unsupported type
```

My original text file has the date and time as to separate columns:

```
GBPUSD<- read.table("GBPUSD.txt", sep=',')

head(GBPUSD)

  V1           V2     V3     V4     V5     V6      V7    V8               
1 <TICKER> <DTYYYYMMDD> <TIME> <OPEN> <HIGH>  <LOW> <CLOSE> <VOL> 
2   GBPUSD     20010102 230100 1.5021 1.5021 1.5018  1.5018     4   
3   GBPUSD     20010102 230200 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019  1.5019     4     
4   GBPUSD     20010102 230300 1.5018 1.5019 1.5018  1.5019     4     
5   GBPUSD     20010102 230400 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019  1.5019     4     
6   GBPUSD     20010102 230500 1.5017 1.5018 1.5017  1.5018     4
```

So the first step I undertook was to blend them into one column using the paste() function in a new 'TIME' column:

```
GBPUSD$Time <-paste(GBPUSD[,2],GBPUSD[,3],sep=",")
```

After which I created a POSIXct time stamp using the new merged 'TIME' (9th column):

```
time<- as.POSIXct(GBPUSD[,9], format="%Y%m%d,%H%M%S")
```

Then I got around to creating an xts time series using the closing prices and time:

```
gbp<- xts(GBPUSD[7], time)
```

However, when I call to.minutes5(gbp), I get an error.

How do I convert the one minute closing prices in my text file to 5 minute prices without running a loop?

Additionally, how would I go about converting 1min OHLC to 5min OHLC?

**UPDATE:**

When I try the advice put forth by khoxsey, I get an error on the following line:

```
raw_cable <- read.table(header=FALSE, text=data, col.names=cn, colClasses=cl)
"Error in textConnection(text) : invalid 'text' argument"
```

I presume this happens because I first imported a tabular data frame and deleted the first line:

```
data<- read.table("GBPUSD.txt", sep=',')
data <- data[-1,] #deleted the initial header to add at a later step, as suggested
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quite providing all of your code, so it's hard to tell exactly where you're going wrong, but you're very close. I copied some of your data to get a few more observations and used your formatting to get the time string. (BTW, `time` is a function in `R` so you might call your variable something else).

The first chunk of code is optional, simply some setup to get a data frame containing representative data, and call your setup to `as.POSIXct` to create our index:

```
forex_data <- "GBPUSD 20010102 230000 1.5021 1.5021 1.5018 1.5018 4
GBPUSD 20010102 230100 1.5021 1.5021 1.5018 1.5018 4
GBPUSD 20010102 230200 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019 4
GBPUSD 20010102 230300 1.5018 1.5019 1.5018 1.5019 4
GBPUSD 20010102 230400 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019 4
GBPUSD 20010102 230500 1.5017 1.5018 1.5017 1.5018 4
GBPUSD 20010102 230600 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019 4
GBPUSD 20010102 230700 1.5018 1.5019 1.5018 1.5019 4
GBPUSD 20010102 230800 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019 1.5019 4
GBPUSD 20010102 230900 1.5017 1.5018 1.5017 1.5018 4
GBPUSD 20010102 231000 1.5017 1.5018 1.5017 1.5018 4"

cn <- c('TICKER','DTYYYYMMDD','TIME','OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','Volume')
cl <- c(rep('character', 3), rep('numeric', 5))
raw_cable <- read.table(header=FALSE, text=forex_data, col.names=cn, colClasses=cl)

dt_tm <-as.POSIXct(paste(raw_cable[,2], raw_cable[,3],sep=","), format="%Y%m%d,%H%M%S")
```

Now that we have a data.frame containing our data, and an appropriate index vector, we create an `xts` object using only the price and volume data. Here, that means the last 5 columns.

```
require(xts)  
cable <- xts(raw_cable[,4:8], order.by=dt_tm)
```

Finally, with a well-formed `xts` object, it is really easy to roll up to 5-minute periods. See the docs for `to.period` for a bunch of other possibilities. One key thing to note here is setting the `indexAt` parameter, which allows us to choose which ending minute to use. For fun, try out the other possibilities in the documentation.

```
to.minutes5(cable, indexAt='startof', name=NULL)

                      Open   High    Low  Close Volume
2001-01-02 23:00:00 1.5021 1.5021 1.5018 1.5019     20
2001-01-02 23:05:00 1.5017 1.5019 1.5017 1.5018     20
2001-01-02 23:10:00 1.5017 1.5018 1.5017 1.5018      4
```

Comment: An issue arises when I try: "raw_cable <- read.table(header=FALSE, text=data, col.names=cn, colClasses=cl)" ["Error in textConnection(text) : invalid 'text' argument"]. I believe this happens because my data is part of an imported tabular data frame: "data<- read.table("GBPUSD.txt", sep=',')". Is there any way around this? Thanks!

Comment: btw, `data` is also a function in R (and so is the commonly-used `df`).